# how to load a xml file in c# windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Im making a game, where i generate the map from a xml file.

Does not WP7 support regular xml? also tried to wrap it inside a XnaContent xml file, but all my nodes a invalid.

How do I go about to load a regular xml file into my c# WP7 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Jon Skeet nailed it on the head, but I had an example where I am doing a read of an xml file from isolated memory I thought I would share.

```
 private const string filePath = "TimeKeeperData.xml";

    private static XDocument ReadDataFromIsolatedStorageXmlDoc()
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!storage.FileExists(filePath))
            {
                return new XDocument();
            }

            using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage))
            {
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(isoFileStream))
                {
                    return XDocument.Load(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows Phone 7 definitely supports regular XML, and it works fine using LINQ to XML to load XML data either from isolated storage, or fetched from the web, or fetched from a resource.

It's unclear *exactly* what you're trying to do or what's going wrong (partly because you've shown no code) but you can certainly use XML in Windows Phone 7. Not being an XNA developer, I don't know about `XnaContent`, but you should potentially try loading it as an `XDocument` first just to check whether that works, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

When you say all your nodes are invalid, it makes me think you might not be handling xml namespaces correctly.  Are you taking them into account, if required?